# Ruby on Rails api with android

Tags: java, android, ruby-on-rails, api, oauth-2.0

I am having trouble getting a 401 unauthorized response from the server,I am doing a "GET" call from a ruby on rails api the oauth token is in the header like this.

```
  urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            OAuth =   "bearer " + Base64.encodeToString(userpass.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
            Log.e("auth", oAuth_token);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", OAuth);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            urlConnection.connect();
```

Userpass  is the actual token.

This works in postman as well as on iOS but android is getting a 401

Answer (score 0):

The Bearer Token Usage specification ([RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750)) is a bit confusing. You don't have to base64-encode the access token before use. To be concrete, your code should be simply like this:

```
OAuth = "Bearer " + userpass;
```

See [this discussion](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/oauth/current/msg08481.html) where the questioner confessed he had had the same confusion as yours.